# Using malloc and free in recursive file scanning function

Tags: c, recursion, memory-management, malloc

I am writing a function that takes in a file-path argument and scans through the directory structure and loads it into a tree. I'm using a recursive function I created called `scan_and_add_children(struct Node* root)` that takes in the root node. The idea is I loop through the files in a directory, add the current node to the tree, and, if it's a directory, I call my recursive function using the current node as the root to add all of that directories children as well. However, I keep getting a `malloc(): corrupted top size` error. I am wondering if the dynamically allocated memory in the `new_node_to_be_added` variable is being lost once I make my recursive call. I can't free the node before the call as it's being used in my recursive function. I am yet to add my function that free()'s the tree, however, I know this is not the issue as I set a break point at the end of main and my program breaks before it even gets out of the function. I'm not super experienced with dynamic memory managenemt so I am trying to use this exercise to get more practice. Can someone explain to me what's going wrong?

Here's my main program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "linkedlist.h"

void scan_and_add_children(struct Node*);
int file_exists(char* path);
struct List* create_list(int level);
struct Node* create_node(int level, char* name);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    if(argc != 2) {
        printf("You must specify one path\n");
        return(-1);
    }
    if(!file_exists(argv[1])) {
        printf("Path not found or not valid\n");
        return(-1);
    }
    struct stat filestat;
    int level = 1;

    struct Node* root = create_node(level, argv[1]);
    struct List* rootList = create_list(1);
    insert_tail(root, rootList);
    //printf("%s\n", root->name);
    stat(root->name, &filestat);
    if(!S_ISDIR(filestat.st_mode)) {    //if root node is a file
        printf("Just a file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        scan_and_add_children(root);
    }
}

void scan_and_add_children(struct Node* root) {
    DIR* dir;
    struct dirent* current;
    struct stat filestat;
    struct Node* new_node_to_be_added;

    dir = opendir(root->name);
    if(dir == NULL)
    {
        perror("Unable to read directory");
        closedir(dir);
        return;
    }
    while((current = readdir(dir))) {
        if(current->d_name[0] == '.') {     //skip files and directories that begin with a .
            continue;
        }

        if(root->name[strlen(root->name)-1] != '/') {       //add in / in order to make opendir functions work
            root->name = strcat(root->name, "/");
        }
        
        char* rootCopy = strdup(root->name);                //using root->name in strcat changes rootcopy and messes up absolute path
        char* absolute_path = strcat(rootCopy, current->d_name);
        //free(rootCopy);
        printf("%s\n", absolute_path);
        
        new_node_to_be_added = create_node(root->children->level, absolute_path);       //create node and add to root->children
        
        insert_tail(new_node_to_be_added, root->children);
        stat(new_node_to_be_added->name, &filestat);
        //print_list(root->children);
        if(S_ISDIR(filestat.st_mode)) {        //if it is a directory, scan and add its children, using new node to be added as root
            scan_and_add_children(new_node_to_be_added);
        }
    }
    free(new_node_to_be_added);
    closedir(dir);
}

int file_exists(char* path) {
    DIR* dir = opendir(path);
    if(dir) {
        closedir(dir);
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

linkedlist.h:

```
struct Node {
    int id;
    char* name;
    struct Node* next;
    struct List* children;
};

struct List {
    int level;
    int count;
    struct Node* head;
    struct Node* tail;
};

struct List* create_list(int level) {
    struct List* list = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
    if (list == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s: Couldn't create memory for the list; %s\n", "linkedlist", strerror (errno));
        exit(-1);
    }
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
    list->count = 0;
    list->level = level;
    return list;
}

struct Node* create_node(int level, char* name) {
    struct Node* node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (node == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Couldn't create memory for the node; %s\n", "linkedlist", strerror (errno));
        exit(-1);
    }
    node->name = strdup(name);
    node->next = NULL;
    node->children = create_list(level+1);
    return node;
}

void insert_tail(struct Node* node, struct List* list) {
    if(list->head == NULL) {
        list->head = node;
        list->tail = node;
        list->count = 1;
        node->id = list->count;
    }
    else {
        list->tail->next = node;
        list->tail = node;
        list->count++;
        node->id = list->count;
    }
}

void print_list(struct List* list) {
    struct Node* node = list->head;
    while(node != NULL) {
        if(node != list->head) {
            printf("->");
        }
        printf("%d", node->id);
        node = node->next;
    }
}

void destroy_list(struct List* list) {
    struct Node* node = list->head;
    struct Node* tmp;
    while(node != NULL) {
        tmp = node;
        node = node->next;
        destroy_node(tmp);
    }
    free(list);
}

void destroy_node(struct Node* node) {
    destroy_list(node->children);
    free(node->name);
}
```

Output:

```
-Surface-Book-2:/home/projects/project1$ ./dirtree /home/projects/
/home/projects/linked-li
/home/projects/project1
dirtree: malloc.c:2379: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
-Surface-Book-2:/home/projects/project1$
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no [mcve]. This is asking for debugging help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    char* rootCopy = strdup(root->name);                //using root->name in strcat changes rootcopy and messes up absolute path
    char* absolute_path = strcat(rootCopy, current->d_name);
```

`strdup` makes an exact sized copy. There's no room to `strcat` on to it. The `strcat` call is almost certainly smashing heap memory that belongs to the memory manager. There may be other places too, but this is the one I spotted. Always make sure you have allocated enough space for what you're storing.

Also this doesn't look right:

```
free(new_node_to_be_added);
```

That's the node you just added to the tree, right? So freeing its memory leaves a hole in your structure that now belongs to the memory manager and you ought not to touch it.

Comment: Well, when would I free that node? Is the memory not lost when the function enters into a new recursive call?

Comment: It was the rootCopy portion you pointed out I had no idea it worked like that thank you!

Comment: The memory isn't lost while you still have a pointer to it. Since you added it into the tree, the tree has a pointer to that memory. It looks like you free everything in `destroy_node()` so you don't need to do it elsewhere, especially not while building the tree. Also consider what would happen if the `while` loop doesn't execute at all, ie. the directory is empty. Then you'd be calling `free()` on an uninitialized pointer. "Early free" or "use after free" are common memory management problems to look out for.